# Sideload non-'Android TV' app to show on the home screen

Tags: system-apps, android-tv, side-loading

I've sideloaded an app on my Xiaomi Mi Box `adb install myapk.apk`. It worked and I can start it. My problem is, that it got installed as system app, which is only accesible over the settings and  prevents me from adding it to the home screen, which makes it really anoying.

Can I sideload an app directly as user app or can I convert a existing system app to a user app?

EDIT:
The app I sideloaded is a tv app of a provider which is supposed to only run on mobile devices, as the distribute apple tv.

Comment: Most likely the app is simply not an AndroidTV cable app. I do remember that as an app developer you have to provide a special entry for starting an app on an AndroidTV. Instead of LAUNCHER the app needs an android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER entry in it's AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @Robert this is most likley, as the provider forces apple tv and therefor only hands out the android app for mobile devices. Is there a workaround how I still can add it to the homescreen? An entry within the favorites list would be already enough.

Comment: As an Android app dev myself, I agree with Robert's comment. I'd suggest rewording the question to "sideload non-'Android TV' app to show on the home screen" instead since I believe this is unrelated to being a system app or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution for me.
As I cannot add the sideloaded app to my home screen, I used this service to generate a launcher app which can be added to the home screen and will start the main app:
http://atvlauncher.trekgonewild.de/index.php