# Android internals: Hide apps from launcher

Tags: android-tv

Android TV box does not show installed app. No matter what Launcher i try the app icon remain invisible. The app can opened from settings.

Is there a blacklist or some database where android does control this for every launcher?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/78465

Comment: Related/possible dupe? [Sideload non-'Android TV' app to show on the home screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232358/44325) which is related to `android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`.

Comment: @AndrewT. built shortcut with Launcher Builder - unfortunately even this apk is not visible in app drawer. tried different launchers like chainfire's sideload launcher. there must be something in the android core itself. btw the desired app is for android tv (double checked android.software.leanback in AndroidManifest.xml)