# How can I restore Chrome capability to my android TV PCs?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have several android TV PCs used as thin clients against a Windows machine. I do some things on the android box and some things in Windows. I've had the current set of TV PCs for about two and a half years and keep them configured exactly the same. Suddenly the Chrome icon disappeared from apps. Chrome is still installed and receives updates but no way exists to open it.

In January I purchased two Hisense 75 inch android TVs. The PlayStore said Chrome was not compatible so I sideloaded. It worked fine for awhile, then I could no longer open Chrome. At the same time I could not open Chrome on the Hisense TVs, the Chrome icons disappeared from all my TV PC workstations.

Probably the Hisense TVs are coincidence, but I wonder if Google maintains an evil person list and added my Google account to it. I could I guess delete the Google account from one of the TV PCs and see if Chrome then works. That seems silly, though. I have no problem with my phones which use the same Google account.

Is there anything I can do to reenable Chrome on the TV PCs? They all came rooted.

device name: TX92 02
model: TX92
android version: 7.1.2
kernel version: 3.14.29

Comment: Regarding the disappearing Chrome icon, consider trying [Sideload non-'Android TV' app to show on the home screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232358/44325)

Comment: I use Nova Launcher on the TV PCs and do not watch TV on them at all. No Android TV stuff.